# Twitter Bootstrap 16-column Responsive CSS, how?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've searched all over for the answer to getting the proper column widths for 16 column bootstrap responsive layouts. 
I've found posts that suggest this can be done. But it does not work for me.
I've tried the Bootstrap customize page. But it doesn't update the responsive part at all. I end up with span16 widths that are 120%+

I tried using the less files and updating the variables. But, again, I end up with wrong widths – for 1200px+ screens, I end up with a 1600px-wide layout.

Perhaps I could update all the values for each screen size individually. But since it's not just the span widths but also inputs and other widths for each screen size, it really starts to get unruly. Especially since I'm not 100% certain what the widths are supposed to be, especially when you get to smaller screen sizes.

There must be others who've run into this issue. So, maybe I'm just being obtuse.

But any guidance or wisdom on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Much thanks.

Comment: "But it doesn't update the responsive part at all. I end up with span16 widths that are 120%+" I don't understand this part, i just downloaded a customized 16-column grid bootstrap and it works fine. What exactly did not work out for you?

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I customize, I put in 16 col, 40px column width, 20px gutter width, yes?

Part of the css it generates is this:
`
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container,
  .navbar-fixed-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 972px;
  }
}`

Comment: i was inaccurate in my last comment. the incorrect size occurs in the 1200px+ version of the css. and anywhere that there are percentages in the responsive css.

Comment: If you are using Less, check out this post: http://toutpt.makina-corpus.org/en/articles/twitters-bootstrap-for-responsive-web-design-with-16-columns

Answer (score 3):

It has been taken care of in the soon to come twitter bootstrap 2.1.0.

[image: Grid System twitter boostrap 2.1.0]